# The number of variables must match the number of parameters in the prepared statement

Tags: php

I use following code to bind parameters, but got still the message:  *The number of variables must match the number of parameters in the prepared statement*

```
if (!isset ($_GET['token']))
{
echo "<p class='passed'>Link passed.</p>";
}
else
{
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE database SET is_verified = ? WHERE token = ?");
$status = 1;
$stmt->bind_param("s", $token);
$stmt->bind_param("i",$status);
$res = $stmt->execute();
if ($res)
{
echo "<p class='NewsStat'>You confirmed.</p>";
}
}
```

The $token value contains 100 characters.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You should bind all parameters with one `bind_param()`. Check the manual. You basically do one parameter, and then again one. Not two. Something like; `$stmt->bind_param("is", $status, $token);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not binding params correctly in your code.

```
if (!isset ($_GET['token']))
{
    echo "<p class='passed'>Link passed.</p>";
}
else
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE database SET is_verified = ? WHERE token = ?");
    $status = 1;
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $status, $token);
    $res = $stmt->execute();
    
    if ($res)
    {
        echo "<p class='NewsStat'>You confirmed.</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried this also, but I don't use a PDO statement but mysqli.
So, it doesn't help :-(

Comment: I have edited my answer for mysqli. Please check.

Comment: Many thanks Abdul, this works great. Some times it is hard to find the problem :-)